# Linking against an existing binary

Tags: gcc, camera, ld, firmware

I'm working on a project which aims to modify a Pentax DSLR's firmware in order to provide [additional functionality](http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/6-pentax-dslr-discussion/250555-resurrecting-pentax-firmware-hacking.html).
As part of this I'm writing/documenting the existing camera's API in C.

I can compile my own code using these API's providing it isn't linked into an ELF binary.

In order for this code to run I need to link it with the existing bare metal firmware. A process that I perform manually by copying the object code into the existing binary and fixing the branch instructions.

Is it possible to use the existing GNU toolchain to link against a pre-existing binary and make the manual process automatic.
I can guess that I would need to provide the following:

- an offset into the existing binary file to use as a base address
- the addresses for all the undefined symbols

I can't see these options in GNU LD.

Is it possible to link a against an existing binary file?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK re-linking of a binary file is not possible.
Linking is actually the step that creates the binary and therefore re-linking of a binary is not possible. 
If you could gather the objects files (the product of assembler) you may be able to create a new binary file.

For more information regarding the build process: http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleW.html